# Why am I getting an error? (controllers, and syntax) CHAPTER 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

EDIT: The real ERROR was this, this is constantly showing up, before was in microposts controller, I reset all (delete, create, see), and now I'm getting the same error but on users.controller when creating a new user.

```
# undefined method `content' for #<User:0x00000103b48238>

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save #the error is supposed to be here.
    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
  else
```

I'm on railstutorial by michael hartl. Yesterday I was trying to make the scaffold app on chapter 2, and I started getting a lot of errors.

So I had to put this piece of code on micropost.rb

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :content, lenght: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

and this is my code

```
class Micropost < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :content, lenght: { maximum: 140 }
end
```

Why did I get an error? Why one single point matters here?

I get another error, a lot of gems were getting a lot of errors ( I DIDN'T TOUCH 1 ), I update the gems and voilá, is this normal?

Comment: What one single point?

Comment: Also, what error do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: `lenght` should be `length`.

Comment: duh, how programmers review this efficiently thank you. P.S. Do you have any idea of what error is that on the EDIT?

Comment: @luigi Would you mind creating a new question for this? I would be happy to help.